# Wikidata labels resolved in SPARQL query browser but not with GET request

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I run this query in the Wikidata query browser:

```
SELECT ?child ?childLabel
WHERE
{
# ?child  father   Bach
  ?child wdt:P22 wd:Q1339.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

The results are as expected, a table with the names of Bach's children. However, if I use the URL provided by the Code facility I get unresolved Q codes for the children rather than their names. Also, if I ask for the description like this:

```
SELECT ?child ?childLabel ?childDescription
WHERE
{
# ?child  father   Bach
  ?child wdt:P22 wd:Q1339.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

I get the description in the table produced by the query browser, but not if I use the URL provided but the Code service.

I have seen questions suggesting intricacies in the wikibase labeling service, but I don't understand the topic enough to make sense of the answer.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Replace `"[AUTO_LANGUAGE]"` with `"en"`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin That worked like a charm! Didn't see that in the tutorial... If you make your comment an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Then accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [User Manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Label_service):

> The Wikidata Query Service website auto-magically replaces `[AUTO_LANGUAGE]` with the language code of **current user's interface**.  For example, if the user's UI is in French, the SPARQL's code `bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en"` will be converted to `bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr,en"` **before being sent** to the query service.

The server doesn't know what is `[AUTO_LANGUAGE]`. Replace `[AUTO_LANGUAGE]` with `en`.

[More info](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/rWDQGef23fb4d85339b3e55efb60376692eaabb1031)

---

And yes, [The word "AUTO" is too broad and confusing.](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T170373#3689703)